# Defining interlockedness

Tags: general-topology, functions

I daresay

> "Two 2D areas are not interlocked iff their border curve is a proper function when viewed from at least one angle"

...but is this correct? The border still may be fractal, infinite and whatnot. I try to clear up:

Definition: Two puzzle pieces are interlocked iff moving them infinitesimally will lead to overlapping.

Hypothesis: Two puzzle pieces are not interlocked if there exists an angle ß such that no straight line with slope ß will cut the boundary in more than one point (and moreover, you can separate the pieces by a parallel transport in direction ß).

[image: Examples]

Comment: Define what is a function when viewed from any angle, because from what I'm thinking that is impossible.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I forgot another "not" :-( I'll edit it.

Comment: @BCLC This has quite a shaky mathematical interpretation, as I see it. We will need to define everything we see here : interlocked (I take this as having an intersection which doesn't contain an open ball), 2D areas (this one refers to subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, perhaps connected sets), "border curve" (which is the intersection of the sets, who knows if it'll be a curve or not), "function when viewed from at least one angle" (There is a $\theta$ such that the border curve rotated by $\theta$ is the graph of some real-valued function). Does everything I say make sense?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon no idea what the question even means lol

Comment: @BCLC I agree, I was wondering why you put the bounty on it, anyway the answer below seems to have something going for it!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon oh i didn't mean the question was unclear. i just didn't have enough background knowledge to understand this question hehe

Comment: @BCLC I see, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what the question means, the following is a counterexample. The areas are colored yellow and green, and their boundary line is black.

They are not interlocked because you can separate them by sliding the yellow piece out in a continuous rotational movement. And however you rotate the black boundary, it will not look like a graph of a function $x \mapsto y$.

[image: Noninterlocked areas]

The converse implication is not true either. The following figure is interlocked, but the boundary has strictly increasing $x$ coordinates when you follow it from the left end to the right end, so looks like a graph of a function.

[image: Interlocked areas]

Comment: Arguably a bit of cheating on the second example (the white void below yellow!) but definitely an answer to accept. I forgot the possibility that parallel transport is not the only way to unlock.

Comment: If you add some more conditions, I believe you can actually have something like the implication(s) that you had in mind. E.g. avoid the white void by stipulating that the two regions are a partition of some convex region (like the square in your original examples).